# Adobe AIR Application to run only with CD

Tags: air, adobe

Developed a desktop application using Adobe Air. The application will get installed through a CD on the users machine. The user should insert the CD every time to access the application.

**Need help is restricting the application from opening without the Cd inserted.**
Have written the following code but does not help.

```
var volumes:Vector.<StorageVolume> = StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo.getStorageVolumes();
for each (var volume:StorageVolume in volumes)
{
    // use isRemovable property for USB:
    if (volume.isRemovable)
        if(volume.File.name == "application")
        {
            Alert.show("Found");
        }
        else
        {
            Alert.show("NOt found","Incorrect Access",4,null,myClickHandler,null,4,null);
            // Define button actions.                   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any Help would be appreciated..